# bash: print all files in directory and subdirectories

Tags: bash, find

## printing all files in directory and sub directories

hey, i am very new to bash and i need to write a One Liner in bash that prints the content of every file in the least recently modified directory and all of it's sub directories.

what is the best way to go about this? 
i tried using the find command that looks useful but i am not sure how to use it for this application, and how do i reach the directory that was least recently used.

thanks in advance to anyone that can help :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Here at StackOverflow, we try and help with programming problems. But it is expected for you to make some effort. Please do some research, have a go yourself and come back with a detailed description on what you tried and what exactly does not work.

Comment: "find . -type d" or "find . -type f" without quotes to use find command. The first param is the folder which you want to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find `ls -t1|head -1` -type f -exec cat {} \;
```